variance partitioning vegan provide results higher than 100%
I am running the variance partitioning function in vegan (varpart). I get the following graph. If you sum them up the total variance reported in the plot is more than 100%. I would expect to be 100-22.6 (residual). If anyone has an idea would be very helpful. Maybe I haven't got how to interpret the graph.
Here is the code I am using:
spe.part.all <- varpart(carb, env.ftp, env.ftm, env.loc)
                       spe.part.all$part 
                       
                       plot(spe.part.all,
                            Xnames = c("FT_PLANT", "MICRO_FG","SOIL_CLIMATE" ), # name the partitions
                            bg = c("seagreen3", "mediumpurple"), alpha = 80, # colour the circles
                            digits = 2, # only show 2 digits
                            cex = 1.5)
                       

Plot variance partitioning:


You did not show the negative components. These should be summed up, too.

@JariOksanen thank you. Where can I find the negative components? I am not sure if there is any and where to find it. thank you

Printing the result or just writing spe.part.all will show the negative components. Same also with summary(spe.part.all). In plot, use argument cutoff = -Inf to be sure that all values are shown (now the plot says "Values <0 not shown").
